# How do I keep the clicked state of a checkbox in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

I'm really having problems with keeping the state of my checkbox in my mvc4 application. I'm trying to send its value down to my controller logic, and refresh a list in my model based on the given value, before I send the model back up to the view with the new values. Given that my checkbox is a "show disabled elements in list" type function, I need it to be able to switch on and off. I've seen so many different solutions to this, but I can't seem to get them to work :(

Here's a part of my view:

```
@model MyProject.Models.HomeViewModel

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="k-block">
            <form action="~/Home/Index" name="refreshForm" method="POST">
                <p>Include disabled units: @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Refresh)</p>
                <input type="submit" class="k-button" value="Refresh" />
           @* KendoUI Grid code *@
        </div>
    </div>
```

HomeViewModel:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public List<UnitService.UnitType> UnitTypes { get; set; }
    public bool Refresh { get; set; }
}
```

The HomeViewController will need some refactoring, but that will be a new task

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(FormCollection formCollection, HomeViewModel model)
{
    bool showDisabled = model.Refresh;

    FilteredList = new List<UnitType>();
    Model = new HomeViewModel();
    var client = new UnitServiceClient();
    var listOfUnitsFromService = client.GetListOfUnits(showDisabled);

    if (!showDisabled)
    {
        FilteredList = listOfUnitsFromService.Where(unit => !unit.Disabled).ToList();
        Model.UnitTypes = FilteredList;

        return View(Model);
    }

    FilteredList = listOfUnitsFromService.ToList();
    Model.UnitTypes = FilteredList;

    return View(Model);
}
```

Comment: Clean up the code into the smallest possible test case, it makes it easier for anyone reviewing it. Ex. "TmpList" isn't defined anywhere.

Comment: Will edit this post now that I got it working. Just need some time to clean it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return your `Model` to your view, so your `Model` properties will be populated, but your checkbox value is not part of your model! The solution is to do away with the `FormCollection` entirely and add the checkbox to your view model:

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    ... // HomeViewModel's current properties go here
    public bool Refresh { get; set; }
}
```

In your view:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Refresh)
```

In your controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HomeViewModel model)
{
    /* Some logic here about model.Refresh */
    return View(model);
}
```

As an aside, I can't see any reason why you'd want to add this value to the session as you do now (unless there's something that isn't evident in the code you've posted.